# i'm getting a sql error

Tags: php, mysql

im getting an error like this:- 
error in

```
INSERT into images_tbl ('images_path','submission_date') values('images/09-08-2014-1407586340.jpg','2014-08-09')
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near ''images_path','submission_date') 
values('images/09-08-2014-1407586340.jpg',' at line 1
```

Here is the query in which i'm getting an error:

```
$query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl ('images_path','submission_date')      values('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use backticks to quote column names in MySQL, not single quotes. But your column names don't need quotes at all. Use

```
INSERT into images_tbl (images_path,submission_date) values('images/09-08-2014-1407586340.jpg','2014-08-09')
```

instead.